# Container Widens When Height Of Explorer Is Reached

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For long time I haven't been able to figure out why the width of my container gets wider when the height of the browser is reached, I mean:

As seen in pictures:

1) [Container hasn't reached the bottom of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRpUe.png)

2) [Container has reached the bottom of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpzkr.png)

As you can see somehow in 2nd picture container width gets bigger.

Now, the given example is shown using text only, however the same thing happens if I use columns inside the main container.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<form id="exmple" runat="server">
    <div class="container well" style="margin-top: 5em;">
        <div class="row">

        <!--sometext content here-->

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What is causing this? No CSS has been modified and no custom CSS files are in use.

Comment: You want the container to stay the same width when having a lot of text in there? Just scrollable?

Comment: I want containter stay the same width regarless of the amount of content I have in it - 1 line, or 10 000 lines. Currently, container becomes bigger if there's a scroll bar.

Comment: by bigger I mean wider.

Comment: I can't see that, but i can see the whole div/container move slightly to the left because of the scroll

Comment: The width doesn't appear to be getting bigger for me either. and yeah, it is slightly moving to the left. because of the scroll. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I see, truth be told, I haven't through of the scroll bar before, maybe it was what was causing the slight move of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the content to "look and have same width/position" whether there is 1 or 1000 lines, do this and there will be a scrollbar all the time.

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` will keep the width of your container to a maximum set amount.

Once content is added the width should not be altered.

You can obtain this through CSS

EDIT: if you want the div itself to be scrollable add the following line `overflow-y: scroll;`
Did not know that was another thing you were looking for.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!